# Can't upgrade Ubuntu 23.04, due to bluetooth driver 'rtbth'

Tags: upgrade, updates, 23.04

I updated to 23.04 a few weeks ago, but the software updater now keeps informing me of new updates but every time I update through this process it fails with the following error message.

I have tried `sudo apt clean`,`sudo apt autoclean`, and `sudo apt autoremove`, but this hasn't helped.

If I use the command line after doing `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`, I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  gir1.2-gtk-4.0 libgtk-4-1 libgtk-4-bin libgtk-4-common
  libgtk-4-media-gstreamer
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 5 not to upgrade.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic (6.2.0-20.20) ...
Setting up linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic (6.2.0-20.20) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.0-20-generic
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rtbth/3.9.7/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rtbth/3.9.7/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/etc/dkms/framework.conf)
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rtbth/3.9.7/source/dkms.conf)

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j16 KERNELRELEASE=6.2.0-20-generic -C /lib/modules/6.2.0-20-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rtbth/3.9.7/build...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/rtbth-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-20-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtbth/3.9.7/build/make.log for more information.
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic:
 linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                            No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                        dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 6.2.0.20.20); however:
  Package linux-headers-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic (6.2.0-20.20) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.0-20-generic
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rtbth/3.9.7/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rtbth/3.9.7/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/etc/dkms/framework.conf)
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rtbth/3.9.7/source/dkms.conf)

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j16 KERNELRELEASE=6.2.0-20-generic -C /lib/modules/6.2.0-20-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rtbth/3.9.7/build...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/rtbth-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-20-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtbth/3.9.7/build/make.log for more information.
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic
 linux-headers-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Output from: `cat /var/lib/dkms/rtbth/3.9.7/source/dkms.conf`

```
PACKAGE_NAME="rtbth"
PACKAGE_VERSION="3.9.7"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[0]="rtbth"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/updates/dkms"
AUTOINSTALL="yes"
REMAKE_INITRD="yes"
```

Comment: `cat /var/lib/dkms/rtbth/3.9.7/source/dkms.conf` please. [edit] your question for output please.

Comment: Thanks, I have edit accordingly, but I couldn't remember how I installed rtbth, as it was a while ago, however, uninstalling through `sudo apt-get remove rtbth-dkms`, seems to have worked. My upgrade now gives me the following message, but seems to be fine? 

`The following packages have been kept back:
  gir1.2-gtk-4.0 libgtk-4-1 libgtk-4-bin libgtk-4-common
  libgtk-4-media-gstreamer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
/var/lib/dkms/rtbth/3.9.7/source/dkms.conf
```

remove the part

```
REMAKE_INITRD="yes"
```

Then let apt try to fix it

```
sudo apt -f install
```